# Should class's properties be unchangeable from everywhere for it to be immutable in C#?

Tags: c#

Consider this class:

```
public class Point
{
    private int x { get; private set; }
    private int y { get; private set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void ChangePoint(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Is this class considered immutable? In other words, for a class to be immutable, should its properties be unchangeable from everywhere or only from outside the class?

Thanks.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I really didn't... At first, people commented here thinking that "ChangePoint" is the constructor. All I did is to clarify that it is not by adding a constructor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, That is the very question. I did not know if `mutable` means "*can not be changed after construction in any case from anywhere.*" or "*cannot be changed **directly** from the outside*". It may be obvious to experienced programmers but not for me, so I think it is a legit question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Thanks. And thanks for upvoting the question after downvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that objects created based on the following class are `immutable`, since there isn't any way of changing `x and y`. They are set only in the construction of the object.

```
class Point
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

That being said the following statement:

```
var point = new Point(3,4);
```

creates an object that behaves like an immutable object. We have to point here, that C# doesn't have inherently immutable data structures. Immutable data structures are common in functional languages like LISP, Haskell etc.

> True, but does my class is called immutable since they are not set in
>   the constructor only?

No, If you add the method **ChangePoint**, then you can't talk about an immutable data structure. Since you modify the object you have created, you alter it's state.

A better way to understand the concept of immutability is the following:

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Add(1);
numbers.Add(2);
```

You create a list and you add 1 and 2. Doing so, you alter the state of the same list each time you add a new item. (For simplification reasons, we don't take account the case where the list has fulled it's capacity and should another array of double size being created copy the elements there and add the new item.)

On the other hand let's say that you have the following list in Haskel:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Then when you will add another element

```
[1,2,3]++[4]
```

a new list would be created and returned, [1,2,3,4]. Each time you add a new item to the list a *new object* is created that contains the elements of the initial list and the newly added element.

However, there is a library that provides your the opportunity to work with immutable collections in C#.

Comment: True, but does my class is called `immutable` since they are not set in the constructor only?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since C# has no immutable types excepting [immutable collections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/), I would apply the following rule:

**A reference type is mutable unless all its properties doesn't change beyond object's construction time and its data is exposed as read-only properties or fields, or constants**.

...or:

**A reference type is immutable unless its properties or fields could be changed beyond construction time**.

BTW, [immutable collections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/) follow above rules: immutability isn't enforced using C# syntax.